# Track and kill a process on timeout using Perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I want to write a Perl script which can monitor a running process. If the process executes for more than expected time,then it should be killed.
I am trying to do this on a `Linux` machine(Linux_x8664).

I cannot achieve the same using `cronjob` because I want to embed the same to another Perl script, which I have been using from a long time.

If you have any suggestions, Please suggest me.

I have a code to do that, But the problem is that my perl script is rinning a process using system command. And I want to track the pid of that invoked process and I want to kill it on timeout.

=========================

```
#!/usr/pde/bin/perl
 my $pid;
 my $finish=0;

 # actions after timeout to keep SIGHANDLER short
 #
 sub timeout {
   print "Timed out pid $pid\n";

   # kill the process group, but not the parent process
   local $SIG{INT}='IGNORE';
   local $SIG{TERM}='IGNORE';
   kill 'INT' = -$$;

   # eventually try also with TERM and KILL if necessary
   die 'alarm';
 }

 eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { $finish=1 };

    alarm 5;

    die "Can't fork!" unless defined ($pid=fork); # check also this!

    if ($pid) { # parent
      warn "child pid: $pid\n";

      # Here's the code that checks for the timeout and do the work:
      while (1) {
        $finish and timeout() and last;
        sleep 1;
      }

      waitpid ($pid, 0);
    }
    else {      # child
      exec (q[perl -e 'while (1) {print 1}'  tee test.txt]);
      exit;     # the child shouldn't execute code hereafter
    }

    alarm 0;

 };

 warn "\$@=$@\n";`enter code here`
 die "Timeout Exit\n" if $@ and  $@ =~ /alarm/;
 print "Exited normally.\n";
 __END__
```

Comment: What is stopping you to write perl script?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there any problems?

Comment: perl scripts support `kill`. Although ideally you'll find a way to uniquely identify the target process,  because there may be dupes in a `ps` list. 
Alternatively - set an alarm signal, because that does it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code - there is a reason why `use strict` and `use warnings` are strongly recommended.

Specifically:

```
Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at line 17, near "$$;"
```

You aren't doing what you think you're doing there.

If you set it to

```
 kill ( 'INT', -$$ );
```

Then you will send a `SIGINT` to the current process group - parent *and* child. I'm not sure why you're doing this when you don't want to kill the parent.

I'd suggest you can simplify this greatly by:

```
else {      # child
  alarm 5;
  exec (q[perl -e 'while (1) {print 1}'  tee test.txt]);
  exit;     # the child shouldn't execute code hereafter
}
```